# Am I using absolute positioning correctly when placing one element over another?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I'm building a demo for an app I want to create and I am trying to create buttons on a mobile phone. I brought in an image of a phone and created buttons set to absolute positioning which allows me to layer them over the phone, but when I go to resize the page, the element moves a lot and does not stay in the same place on the phone. How can I fix this? Please see fiddle to see exactly what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/x313vkup/

I would really appreciate a modification of my fiddle link so I can understand how this works.
This is a snippet of the code that shows the list set to absolute positioning:

```
#phone_view {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -65%;
 margin-left: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of `position:absolute` is that you can accomplish a lot without setting margins -- you can go straight to using `top`, `left`, etc.

An absolutely-positioned element needs to be positioned relative to a wrapper, however. I would recommend setting your `#phone` element to `position: relative` and then setting the position and dimensions of `#phone_view` "manually" in the CSS.

I would also recommend creating another wrapper element inside of phone to act as the relatively positioned element, since your `h4` can wrap onto a second line, drive down the phone image, and get it out of sync with the absolute positioning.

EDIT: [link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x313vkup/21/). Note the relatively-positioned wrapper (`.phone-wrap`). Child elements with `position: absolute` will define their position based on this wrapper. Also, no need for margins on `#phone_view`.

Also, re: `#phone_view`, `background-color` is just to make it visible for the demo, and while `overflow: auto` seemed appropriate for the demo, it doesn't affect the positioning of the object itself.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that in my fiddle? I've always struggled with this concept and would really appreciate it.